# Moving Google Sheets Project to Client's G-Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-apps-script

**BACKGROUND:**

I have a project folder in Google Drive that contains
- 2 Spreadsheets
- 1 Folder

There are several scripts attached to the Spreadsheets. One of these scripts create n number of copies of the spreadsheet and place them all in the folder. Another script takes in data from copies created in the folder.

Point is the Spreadsheets and Folder are accessing each other using Apps Scripts. [files/folders IDs are being used in the script]

All of this is working smoothly on my Google Drive (consumer account: gmail.com domain). Now I would like to transfer it all to my client's Google Drive (on a different G-Suite domain).

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE:**

I want to move a working copy of this project to my client's Drive with all scripts and permissions working correctly.

What is the best way to achieve this?

- I know ownership cannot be transferred to an account on a different domain.
- I am not sure if creating a copy will keep the IDs same or the scripts need to be updated.
- If I move a copy of the folder to a shared place in client's drive, will the client require allowing permissions again?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> - I am not sure if creating a copy will keep the IDs same or the scripts need to be updated.

File ID's are unique to each file. If you make a copy, the copy will have a different file ID from the original.

> - If I move a copy of the folder to a shared place in client's drive, will the client require allowing permissions again?

Google Apps Script authorizations are Script Project based so moving them from one folder to another will not require a new authorization.